# How to refresh the Recycler View on TextView change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler View list. I want to refesh the Recycler View on TextView value change

Comment: Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page and edit your question. Too few information.

Comment: It is a better idea if you can track these changes at a Adapter level because the whole idea of a recycler view is to abstract data from the UI in principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try? :

```
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        //Refresh your view, make network calls to server or something
  }
});
```