# Update the recycler view textview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` defined in my android project. The `Adapter` for the `RecyclerView` is as follows

```
public class CustomAdapter1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter1.MyViewHolder>  {
    private Fragment1 myFrag;
    private ArrayList<DataModel1> dataSet;
    DBHandler db;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView butAccept,butReject;
    TextView nick,stat,tit,cat,desc,dt;
    public CardView cardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.nick = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nick);
        this.stat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stat);
        this.tit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tit);
        this.cat = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat);
        this.desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        this.dt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dt);
        this.butAccept = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.accept_textview);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cardView.setOnClickListener(this);
        butAccept.setOnClickListener(this);
        db = new DBHandler(itemView.getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if( v.getId() == butAccept.getId()){
            String x = String.valueOf(dataSet.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMeetId());

            myFrag.showToast(x);
        }

    }

}

public CustomAdapter1(ArrayList<DataModel1> data,Fragment1 frag) {
    this.dataSet = data;
    myFrag = frag;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardfrag1, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,final int listPosition) {
    TextView nick = holder.nick;
    TextView stat = holder.stat;
    TextView tit = holder.tit;
    TextView cat = holder.cat;
    TextView desc = holder.desc;
    TextView dt= holder.dt;
    nick.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getNick());
    stat.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getStat());
    tit.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getTit());
    cat.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getCat());
    desc.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getDesc());
    dt.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getDt());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
}
```

The final `TextView` `butAccept` has dynamic values.I have an internal DB that has the column `Status`. When the value of the `Status` is 1 I need to change the text that is being displayed in the `TextView butAccept`.

How should I do this? Should I write a function in my `CustomAdapter`, or in the fragment in which I am using the adapter?

In my Fragment I have a function :

```
 private void checkTheAcceptStatus(int x){
        int status = db.getMeetingStatus(x);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),String.valueOf(status),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(status == 1){

        }

    }
```

This function is being called everytime a new item is added to the adapter. The internal DB is being queried correctly and if the value of `Status` is being returned. If the value is 1 what should I do?

I [saw this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29419660/how-to-refresh-the-recycler-view-on-textview-change) but this is unclear and I was unable to come to any conclusion from this.

Comment: where does `ArrayList<DataModel1> dataSet` come from? from your sqlite DB too?

Comment: No..It is from the online DB.

Comment: `DataModel1` is the schema of the data that I am receiving from the online DB and `MeetingList` is the schema of the data that is used by the SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly every row in your list has this accept button. So in your onBindViewHolder() you cant set the buttons text depending on the state of your status variable. When you detect changes in your db you can use the various notify methods provided depending on your needs: notifyItemChanged(...), notifyItemRangeChanged(...), notifyItemAdded(...), notifyItemRemoved(...) etc. Your onBindViewHolder should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder vh, int position) {
    if(dataSet.get(position).getStatus() == 1){
        vh.butAccept.setText("Your status 1 case text here");
    } else {
        vh.butAccept.setText("Your status not 1 case text here"); 
    }
}
```

Also you can just use notifyDataSetChanged() if you want to refresh the whole list, but the methods above are more efficient.

Comment: should I call these methods periodically or will they be triggered when the change happens?

Comment: You should call them when you know your data has changed. If you want your list to update periodically you have to implement the logic that checks your database or where you get your data from yourself. When you detect that your data has changed use the notify methods and the adapter will call onBindViewHolder(...) for the rows that need to be updated.